# Eclipse development - change FieldEditor based on new value of other FieldEditor inside FieldEditorPreferencePage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

In [Nodeclipse preference Page](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/preferences/NodePreferencePage.java)
I want that expressVersion is updated when expressPath is changed.

I am adding code below, however it does not fire PropertyChangeEvent so this logic does not get executed.
What is wrong here?

```
    expressPath = new FileFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.EXPRESS_PATH, "Express path:", getFieldEditorParent());
    //TODO update expressVersion on expressPath selection
    IPropertyChangeListener listener = new IPropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (event.getProperty().equals(FieldEditor.IS_VALID)) {
                String newValue = (String) event.getNewValue();
                expressVersion.setStringValue( ProcessUtils.getCurrentVersionOf(newValue) );
            }
        }               
     };
    expressPath.setPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    addField(expressPath);

    expressVersion = new StringFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.EXPRESS_VERSION, "Selected Express version:", getFieldEditorParent());
    expressVersion.setEnabled(false, getFieldEditorParent());
    addField(expressVersion);
```

Comment: Does it fire when you use the button to select a different file or is it just when you type in the text field?

Comment: no, it does not fire. I use Debug as -> Eclipse application, if that may matter

Comment: The `IS_VALID` property is only fired when the valid state changes. Is the field ever invalid?

Comment: The problem is that propertyChange( is not called. And for Eclipse setting PropertyChangeListener is the only way to get callback on change.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at sources of FieldEditorPreferencePage, I found that `initialize()`
is resetting PropertyChangeListeners for all fileds

```
/**
 * Initializes all field editors.
 */
protected void initialize() {
    if (fields != null) {
        Iterator<FieldEditor> e = fields.iterator();
        while (e.hasNext()) {
            FieldEditor pe = e.next();
            pe.setPage(this);
            pe.setPropertyChangeListener(this);
            pe.setPreferenceStore(getPreferenceStore());
            pe.load();
        }
    }
}
```

initialize() is called after createFieldEditors();

```
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    fieldEditorParent = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;
    fieldEditorParent.setLayout(layout);
    fieldEditorParent.setFont(parent.getFont());

    createFieldEditors();

    if (style == GRID) {
        adjustGridLayout();
    }

    initialize();
    checkState();
    return fieldEditorParent;
}
```

So it is solved with code below

```
@Override
protected void initialize() {
    super.initialize();
    expressPath.setPropertyChangeListener(new MyPropertyChangeListener(this));
}

private class MyPropertyChangeListener implements IPropertyChangeListener{

    private FieldEditorPreferencePage page;

    public MyPropertyChangeListener(FieldEditorPreferencePage nodePreferencePage) {
        page = nodePreferencePage;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        page.propertyChange(event);

        // The IS_VALID property is only fired when the valid state changes.
        if (event.getProperty().equals(FieldEditor.IS_VALID)) {
            isValidPath = ((Boolean) event.getNewValue()).booleanValue();
            if (!isValidPath) {
                expressVersion.setStringValue( "Selected path is not valid" );
            }
            return;
        }
        if (!isValidPath) { // if it is still not valid file, we don't need to check again
            return;
        }
        if (event.getProperty().equals(FieldEditor.VALUE)) {
            String newExecutablePath = (String) event.getNewValue();
            expressVersion.setStringValue( ProcessUtils.getCurrentVersionOf(newExecutablePath));
        }
    }
}
```